# LilyPond: how do I place a hairpin under a slur?

Tags: lilypond

Here is the desired engraving (look at the last 4 notes of the left hand):

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
sib4 la8 sol16 \< (la \! \clef bass
\once \override Hairpin.outside-staff-priority = #0
sib \> la fa \! sol)
```

`outside-staff-priority` had no effect.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slurs are not placed as outside staff elements, but directly drawn into the score. But this means that outside staff elements like Hairpins will be placed ouside of the slur (which is part of the staff). The solution is rather simple: Tell Lilypond that your Hairpin (or rather its `parent`, the `DynamicLineSpanner`) is not an outside staff object. This is done by setting `outside-staff-priority` to `##f`.

```
\language "italiano"

{
  sib4 la8 sol16 \< _(la \! \clef bass
  \once\override DynamicLineSpanner.outside-staff-priority = ##f
  sib \> la fa \! sol)
}
```

Alternatively you could make the Slur an outside staff element

```
\language "italiano"

{
  sib4 la8 sol16 \< 
  \tweak outside-staff-priority #10
  _(la \! \clef bass
  \once\override DynamicLineSpanner.outside-staff-priority = #0
  sib \> la fa \! sol)
}
```

But this is usually not a good idea, as this will render the Slur shape optimization meaningless (after all the Slur is optimized for a very specific position).

Comment: For your alternative solution, I think you need to move the `\once\override Slur.outside-staff-priority = #10`, to before the `sol16 \< _(`.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Yes. Replaced it with a tweak. The former does still work because it creates an unattached slur even, which is then applied to the previous note.

Comment: Thank you! Gosh, a solution, more often than not, is quite simple. I hope I will learn how to solve LilyPond puzzles.